# Survey Monkey API Events

Tags: javascript, api, events, surveymonkey

I am trying to embed a simple survey into a popup and integrate it with my application. The popup needs to contain a survey question that will be capture the user's response using a two option radio button. Once the user selects a radio option I need to trigger an event to enable the submit button. Once the submit button is clicked, I need to trigger another event to kick off other processes in the application. Is this possible with the Survey Monkey API?
Thanks, Tyler

Answer (score 0):

The SurveyMonkey API is read only, so I don't think it will solve your problem.  You can embed surveys in an iframe though.